# Highlighting polygons of Mapbox tileset on hover?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

I am trying to highlight polygons from a Mapbox tileset on a map on hover. Based on [Mapbox's tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/) I am adding a feature state `hover` to the data that is set through `mousemove` and `mouseleave` events. The data's paint attributes depend on the `hover` state.

That works fine with a GEOJSON source as in their example. My source is a tileset though, and that does not seem to work properly: polygons that are entirely within one tile are rendered just as expected. Polygons that span several tiles are rendered incorrectly: they change their appearance only until the edge of the current tile. Zooming in and out -- which changes the size of the tiles -- verifies that.

Is it possible to add such a hover effect on data from a tileset?

Comment: How are you generating your Mapbox Tileset, GeoJSON upload to mapbox.com, tippecanoe, etc? Make sure you have an `id` set.

Comment: I am uploading GeoJSON within the Mapbox Studio, yes. The data has an `id` which is a string. I also thought the ID may be the problem, but because it works fine for polygons within tiles I rejected the idea of the ID being the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight all parts of a feature that is spread across tiles, Mapbox needs a way to associate features across tiles. Usually this is done via the `id` field in the vector tiles. When uploading a shapefile (or other data source) to Mapbox Studio, this is automatically done for you. If you're generating vector tiles yourself, e.g. with Tippecanoe, specify `--generate-ids` to ensure that features that span multiple tiles get assigned the same ID.

Once you've uploaded your data to Mapbox Studio, you can build upon the tutorial you linked and change the source to a vector tile source:

```
map.addSource("states", {
    "type": "vector",
    "url": "mapbox://kkaefer.1zk6ono0"
});
```

Then, add the `source-layer` property to the `addLayer` calls, and add the same name as the `sourceLayer` property to `setFeatureState`.

For a more thorough tutorial, have a look at https://blog.mapbox.com/going-live-with-electoral-maps-a-guide-to-feature-state-b520e91a22d

Comment: The "id" was the problem. I tried different ways of uploading my data to Mapbox Studio, and the hovering never worked properly. The only way of making this work for me was the Tippecanoe hint, in particular the `tippecanoe -o output.mbtiles -zg --drop-densest-as-needed --generate-ids input.geojson` command from the tutorial you linked. Thanks! If you remove the direct Mapbox Studio upload as a solution, this would be the correct solution for me.

Comment: The last time I checked while Studio creates an id field, this is not unique. Tippecanoe, vtile, geojson uploaded in the client and styled in GL JS, and many other vector tile generators do allow for the creation of unique ids.